# Total float and Free float basic difference

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Why we calculate total float and free float what is the basic difference between them?
and also What is the difference between PERT and CPM ?...

Answer (score 4):

**Total Float**

Total float is measured as the difference between the early and late start dates (LS - ES) or the early and late finish dates (LF – EF).

Total float represents the amount of time an activity can be delayed without delaying the overall project duration and is also called “float” or “slack”.

**Example**

If activity 1 has a duration of 6 days and is occurring concurrently with activity 2 which has a duration of 9 days, activity 1 has 3 days of total float. Meaning, it can be delayed up to three days without any effect on the project.

However, if activity 1 is delayed by 5 days, there is now a negative float situation: -2 days. This reflects the fact that the project will now take two days longer than anticipated.

**Free Float**

Free float is measured by subtracting the early finish (EF) of the activity from the early start (ES) of the successor activity.

Free float represents the amount of time that a schedule activity can be delayed without delaying the early start date of any immediate successor activity within the network path.
Free float is only calculated on the last activity in an activity sequence.

**Example**
If Company XYZ has 100 million total shares outstanding, and 30 million are restricted shares, then the free float would be the remaining 70 million shares available for trading (100 million - 30 million = 70 million).

From [Source](http://www.passionatepm.com/blog/total-float-versus-free-float-pmp-concept-18)

Concerning **PERT & CPM**

- PERT is probabilistic whereas CPM is deterministic
- In CPM, estimates of activity duration are based on historical data
- In PERT, estimates are uncertain and we talk of ranges of duration and the probability that an activity duration will fall into that range
- CPM concentrates on Time/Cost trade off.

Comment: same way can you explain free float with example ?

Comment: please explain "independent float" also

Answer (score 4):

Floats in Projects are of 4 types:

1. Total Float : Obtained by deducting the Early start and the activity duration from the Late finish of the activity. That means, we can get both the slacks obtained from Late start / Early Start, as well as from Late Finish / Early Finish. Thus, Total Float signifies the total slack time available for any activity in the Project without delaying the overall Project's duration.
2. Safety Float: Obtained by deducting Late start plus the activity duration from the Late Finish of activity. That means, we have the slack time available due to time of Late finish / Early early finish of the activity. This Float does not interfere with the float time available by the Predecessor activity.
3. Free Float: Obtained by deducting the Early start plus the activity duration from the Early Finish of the Activity. We have the slack time available due to time of Early Start / Late Start of the activity. However, this float does not eat away the slack time available for the successor activity.
4. Independent Float: Obtained by deducting the Late start plus the activity duration from the Early Finish. This float virtually leaves no time for breathing since, the predecessor activity has started late, and the successor activity is scheduled for an early start, after utilizing the time duration for the activity. Most of the time, the slack time available is ZERO for this float.

Answer (score 0):

**Total Float** - Amount of time that an activity may be delayed from early start without delaying the project finish date.

**Free Float** - Amount of time a task can be delayed without delaying the early start of its successor.

Answer (score 0):

consider one activity A have total duration of  6 days and its successor activity B is starting 3 days after completing of activity A than the free float between tho activities is 3 .means there will not be any impact on activity B even activity A gets delayed by 3 Days.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this post for an example:

http://www.deepfriedbrainproject.com/2009/08/total-free-float-cpm-network-diagram.html